# Numa aplicação do Flutter no Android Studio uma mensagem de erro é exibida ao modificar algo no build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Esse erro ocorre quando eu modifico alguma coisa no build.gradle da pasta "app" de alguma aplicação do Flutter no Android Studio.

Assim, logo ao clicar no arquivo, já aparece o sublinhado vermelho de erro no nome do arquivo e, quando tento rodar a aplicação aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM J500M in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 busy and 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\kleve\Desktop\Documentos\Flutter\chat_online\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Command: 
C:\Users\kleve\Desktop\Documentos\Flutter\chat_online\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Isso que tem na linha 24 do build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: Pesquisei um pouco sobre o erro que você reportou acima, aprece ser algo referente a ao gradlle. Talvez isso possa ajudar. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41492#issuecomment-536112970

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei o que aconteceu, mas nas últimas versões do Flutter isso foi corrigido, assim, eu apenas modifiquei o que eu queria nos arquivos "gradle", ignorei os erros e reiniciei a IDE, logo o app compilou. 
Quando eu tentava compilar o App sem reiniciar a IDE, esse erro acontecia.